# Failing an IF condition sooner

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements

Suppose I have this IF

```
if ([self verifyCondition1] && [self verifyCondition2])
```

will Objective-C execute both `verifyCondition` methods before failing? or will it fail as soon as `verifyCondition1` fails?

My idea is not to execute any code that is not needed and speed up execution.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't spend 30 seconds testing the code yourself before posting this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard specifies short-circuit evaluation, which is the "technical" term for what you are asking about.  Thus, if `[self verifyCondition1]` returns NO/FALSE, execution immediately continues to the `else` block, if any, or to the code following the `if` statement.

Comment: ah, thanks about that. I was suspecting that but wanted to confirm. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Verify it for yourself bro. You can make sure by that. Avi is correct about it. If condition one fails, it fires else.

```
- (BOOL)check1 {
    NSLog(@"condition 1");
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)check2 {
    NSLog(@"condition 2");
    return YES;
}


if ([self check1] && [self check2]) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from 'C' background then this shouldn't be much of a mind-boggling thing.

Since you are doing a conditional check on two values, the values could be True/False (YES/NO) and the expression checks for the **short-circuit** of both.

**The result is obvious, if first condition fails then it will never check following conditions.**

The following screen shot depicts the same.

[image]

***Is this helpful anywhere?***

Yes, indeed.

Few examples as :

```
if (array.count>0 && [array[0] isEqualToString:@"someString"]){
  ...
}
```

Other example:

```
if ([returnedObject isKindofClass:[MyBoxClass class]] && returnObject.length * returnedObject.bredth>0){
    ....
}
```